# show grants on function gives 'does not exist or not authorized' to account admin even though function exists in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod.bi.sla_hours_between(
    t_start timestamp_ntz,
    t_end timestamp_ntz
)
    RETURNS NUMBER(38,4)

AS $$
SELECT bi.sla_hours_between_base(convert_timezone('UTC','Europe/Berlin', t_start), convert_timezone('UTC','Europe/Berlin', t_end))
$$;
```

and if I run `show user functions like 'SLA_HOURS_BETWEEN'`  I can see it exists:
[image]

However if I run `show grants on function prod.bi.sla_hours_between()`  as accountadmin I get the following error:

`SQL compilation error: Function 'PROD.BI.SLA_HOURS_BETWEEN' does not exist or not authorized.`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give function parameters:

```
show grants on function prod.bi.sla_hours_between(timestamp_ntz, timestamp_ntz );
```